# SSRS Showing Authentication Error

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I am running a Reports Server (SSRS) and I am calling the reports from within my ASP application. Whenever I try to load a report through the site itself it shows me a HTTP 401 Error, both locally and accessing through the domain. If I open the reports in the ReportServer itself I can open them up fine, the problem is loading through the web page. I tried changing the credentials in the data source itself but everything was fine, switched the SQL User credential and Windows Authentication and nothing helped. Any help would be appreciated as I am at a loss about what to do.

This is the local server error:

```
[WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.]
  Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.GetSecureMethods() +232
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.IsSecureMethod(String methodname) +60
 Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.RSExecutionConnection.SetConnectionSSLForMethod(String methodname) +16
     Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Internal.Soap.ReportingServices2005.Execution.ProxyMethodInvocation.Execute(RSExecutionConnection connection, ProxyMethod`1 initialMethod, ProxyMethod`1  retryMethod) +831
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.SoapReportExecutionService.LoadReport(String report, String historyId) +34
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.EnsureExecutionSession() +175
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ServerReport.SetParameters(IEnumerable`1 parameters) +162
 System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3178
```

ASPX Codebehind:

```
 ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new System.Uri("serveradress");
            ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/TrialBalance";
            Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter[] Param = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter[1];
            Param[0] = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("ID", Convert.ToString(Session["BranchID"]));

            ReportViewer1.ShowParameterPrompts = false;
            ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(Param);
            ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

**Attempts!**
1) Gave AppPool LocalSystem permissions

2) i can access the Reportserver using domain.com/ReportServer or localhost/ReportServer, problem only occurs within the ASP app.

3) Verified SSRS Service Account permissions.

4) DataSource connects without issue.

5) The reports were working without issue a week ago, I migrated a server image to another more powerful server and I believe this is were it got broken but I don't see how as the image is the SAME. Nothing changed.

6) I can call the ReportServer (Report Loads and all) in my local development computer, which aims at the remote server. If I access the same ASPX in the website it gives me the HTTP 401 error

7) Changed in programing to aim at localhost directly... this was the error:

```
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
    Cannot create a connection to data source 'DataSource1'. (rsErrorOpeningConnection)
        Cannot open database "CoopBranches" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.
```

Which is weird because I am testing the data source and it is connecting without any issue.

Comment: I would guess that this is because the account that your ASP.NET site is running under does not have access to the SSRS Report Server. You will need grant Report Server access to this account. If you are using Windows Auth in your DataSource then you need to ensure that this account also has access to the underlying database.

Comment: Could you post the .NET code that is calling the SSRS web service?  Also, how do you have the authentication set up for the SSRS websites in IIS Manager?  Finally, if this request going from one server to another (e.g., from a web server to a database server), are the firewalls set up to allow the request through?

Comment: Posted the code. Will check the SSRS permissions, but I remember they previously worked without issues and I hadn't dabbled into permissions. Will check it though!

Comment: Will check firewalls, though for the scale of the project I have both webserver and database server in the same server (can easily split them in the future) so I don't think there are firewall issues.

Comment: Find the account that IIS is using to run the application pool. Make sure that account has access to report server. If you are trying to do pass-thru authentication, to use the user's permissions, then you have a lot of Kerberos configuration to do.

Comment: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool... added it with Browse permissions to SSRS. No go. I changed the DefaultAppPool user to LocalSystem as suggested elsewhere and no go. Windows Account has access to DB as well. I am stuck... =/

Comment: I can also connect remotely to domain.com/ReportServer and load the reports.

Comment: I'm having similar issue, it just stopped suddenly today. Did you figure out the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I came across with the same issue several days ago and here are some suggestions based on what I did on mine.

1. On you app pool try to indicate/impersonate a domain user then give that report permissions on the server.
2. This one gives a big difference.  Try to see what ReportViewer1 is resolving to, what I notice is that if your application goes to

**http://{YourReportServerURL}/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/{YourReportName}&{Param1}={ParamValue}**

Then you will have a multi hop authentication issue beacuse that URL Redirects to another URL that eventually resolves to, loosing the authenticated user in the process when not using Kerberos

**http://{YourReportServerURL}/ReportServer?/{YourReportFolder}/{YourReportName}&{Param1}={ParamValue}**

If thats the case try to generate the URL manually like such

**http://{YourReportServerURL}/ReportServer?/{YourReportFolder}/{YourReportName}&{Param1}={ParamValue}**